# Using Asyncio subprocess in a pyramid view

Tags: pyramid, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I am trying to run a asyncio sub-process in a pyramid view but the view hangs and the async task appears to never complete. I can run this example outside of a pyramid view and it works.

With that said I have tested originally using `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` but this tells me `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-2'`

There are certainly things I don't fully understand here. Like maybe the view thread is different to the main thread so `get_event_loop` doesn't work.

So does anybody know why my async task might not yield its result in this scenario? This is a naive example.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def async_task(dir):
    # This task can be of varying length for each handled directory
    print("Async task start")
    create = asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        'ls',
        '-l',
        dir,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    proc = yield from create

    # Wait for the subprocess exit
    data = yield from proc.stdout.read()
    exitcode = yield from proc.wait()
    return (exitcode, data)


@view_config(
    route_name='test_async',
    request_method='GET',
    renderer='json'
)
def test_async(request):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    dirs = ['/tmp/1/', '/tmp/2/', '/tmp/3/']
    tasks = []
    for dir in dirs:
        tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(async_task(dir), loop=loop))

    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
    loop.close()
    return
```

Comment: Pyramid framework is not compatible with asyncio, there is no reason to use them together.

Comment: I had a feeling it might be something like this. I am still interested why? I have noticed that uWSGI server has an experimental feature to use asyncio, would this change its behavior?

Comment: No. Pyramid is a WSGI framework. WSGI is synchronous by the standard definition.

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/housleyjk/aiopyramid ?

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking `loop.run_until_complete` in your view so clearly it is going to block until complete!

If you want to use asyncio with a WSGI app then you need to do so in another thread. For example you could spin up a thread that contains the eventloop and executes your async code. WSGI code is all synchronous and so any async code must be done this way, with it's own issues, or you can just live with it blocking the request thread like you're doing now.

Comment: I am actually ok with the blocking. As the non-naive example I have in my code runs a sub-process on a list of files. Each file is of varying size and will have different processing time. So running the task in parallel is an efficient way of doing the job.